# Python3 int.__sizeof__() produces syntax error

Tags: python, oop, integer

The following code produces a syntax error. Does anyone know why syntax errors result when using object attributes?

```py
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 27 2020, 09:35:23) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>1.__sizeof__()
  File &quot;&lt;stdin
    1.__sizeof__()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The lexer is greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#other-tokens), so it recognizes `1.__sizeof__()` as `float` literal `1.` followed by an identifier `__sizeof__`, rather than an `int` literal followed by a `.` operator.

```
$ python -m tokenize <<< "1.__sizeof__()"
1,0-1,2:            NUMBER         '1.'
1,2-1,12:           NAME           '__sizeof__'
1,12-1,13:          OP             '('
1,13-1,14:          OP             ')'
1,14-1,15:          NEWLINE        '\n'
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Use parentheses to <strike>override</strike> assist the lexer:

```
>>> (1).__sizeof__()
28
```

Comment: Or add a second dot `1..__sizeof__()`.

Comment: @VisioN: But that gives you a float instead of an int, which matters.

Comment: Would this be possible to have been found out by looking at Python's grammar specification? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah yeah, you are right. Parens are more appropriate here.

Comment: The grammar stops short of defining literals, referring only to things like `STRING` and `NUMBER`.

Comment: @RandomDavis: No, because this is a tokenization issue. You'd want the [lexical analysis docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for that.

Comment: (Or at least, the lexical analysis docs would be the appropriate place to document this. I'm not sure whether it's actually documented there.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica It's there, just not obvious. Section 2.2 ends with "Where ambiguity exists, a token comprises the longest possible string that forms a legal token, when read from left to right." So given the choice between `1`/`.` and `1.`, it goes with `1.`.

Comment: Ah, there it is.